# Dynamic content mousehover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseevent

I have a dynamically generated html-content: div with `class='dynamicWrap'`. I need to handle mouse hover on this element:

```
    $(document).on('mouseover', '.dynamicWrap', function() {
        console.log('test');
    });
```

The problem is that I see 'test' 200 times (I have 200 divs with `dynamicWrap` class). How can I handle only one event for the exact div I have hovered?

Comment: You need to use `mouseenter` event instead of `mouseover`. It will detect when the mouse enters the element (use mouseleave to detect when quitting the element).

Comment: If I got you right, you're trying to make the hover function only happen once? On jQuery there's a function for it .http://api.jquery.com/one/ If that's not what you meant I'm sorry, could you be a bit more detailed please.

Comment: @JoelHernandez Yes, I want the hover function only happen once. But `one` didn't help me. I'm still receiving 200 'test' :(

Comment: $(".dynamicWrap").one('mouseover', function() {}) Maybe?

Comment: `$(document).one('mouseover', '.dynamicWrap', function(){})` ?

Comment: Am I missing something? I'm not seeing the problem at all. I only get a log for the element I hover on. EG: http://jsfiddle.net/a7rvP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('dynamicWrap')) {
        $(e.target).mouseover(function() {
            console.log('test');
        });
    }
});
```

Note that this needs to run before you start dynamically adding new divs.

Comment: This doesn't work when `dynamicWrap` is generated dynamically.

Comment: The main idea is that I should execute this code before inserting new divs. Thanks.

Comment: Another method of dealing with this problem is to assign the mouseover in the same function which creates the element.

Comment: this is not a cross-browser solution. IE will not work.

Comment: I dont think the term "cross browser solution" should include IE8,but anyway, my comment about assigning the mouse over when the element is created would work in IE8.

Comment: Oh I misread your comment, why wouldn't that work in IE in general? DOMNodeInserted is supported in IE9+

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".dynamicWrap").one('mouseover', function() {

//Function content here.
alert("I've been hovered! Only happen once!")

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will unbind mouseover event on hover:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.dynamicWrap', function() {
    console.log('test');
    $(this).off('mouseover');
});
```